EF Core 3 - Parent / Children relationship stored in same databse table
I have the following classes
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children{ get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

I tried to simplify my class structure here. Both classes will have different properties, so I really need to have two different classes / types.
I'm looking to store this data in a flat / single database table with the following structure:
ParentId - ParentName - ChildId - ChildName

I tried numerous combinations of fluent configurations but haven't been able to generate a table this way.
I still need the two entities to be linked when I will fetch back my data from the database.
Note that I'm using EF Core 3.1, so ComplexType are not supported yet in this version.

Do you really need a one-to-many relationship? Or will one-to-one be enough?

Maybe you need inheritance? This will allow you to place different types in the same table.

@AlexanderPetrov one-to-many is needed. I was able to do it in on-to-one relationship, one-to-many is more tricky and doesn't seems to be possible
